# How to change the loop Powershell content from the csv file automatically?

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to change the loop PowerShell content from the CSV file automatically, is there someone know how to achieve the goal?

I want to run the loop PowerShell as below,I export the AD Group Members UPN with CSV file like One@contoso.com. I want to change the `Userlist` with the UPN automatically because there have more than 1000 members in the group and I have to change the upn from `one@contoso.com` to `'one@contoso.com'`,it’s easy to make a miss, is there has a smart way can achieve the goal,thanks.

> Export-ADGroupmember UPN:

```
Get-ADGroupmember -identity adgroup | % { get-aduser $_.samaccountname | select userprincipalname } | export-csv upn.csv -notypeinformation
```

> Loop PowerShell:

```
Loop PowerShell:
$UserList = @(
    'One@contoso.com'
    'Two@contoso.com'
    'Three@contoso.com'
    'Four@contoso.com'
    'Five@contoso.com'
    )

foreach ($UL_Item in $UserList)
    {
    $ARAGU_Params = @{
        TenantName = "contoso"
        HostPoolName = "contosoHostPool"
        AppGroupName = "Desktop Application Group"
        UserPrincipalName = $UL_Item
        }
    Add-RdsAppGroupUser @ARAGU_Params
}
```

Comment: You say you need to change the UserPrincipleName from `one@contoso.com` to `one@contoso.com`, but.. where's the difference? Can you give us a better example?

Comment: you don't show any connection between your `Get-ADGroupmember` call and the `$UserList` collection. is there one? in the previous Question, i meant that you should automatically populate that $Var with the output of something like `Get-AdUser`. perhaps `$UserList = (Get-ADGroupmember -Identity $TargetGroup).SamAccountName`. ///// i don't have AD access, so you would need to tweak that to something that actually _works_. [*grin*]

Comment: @Theo I think there have a  ""  marks. I think it will have some effects.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, you are right. I am sorry that I am new to PowerShell. By the way, last time you told me how to show the outputs, is there a code can show how many users I added?

Comment: @Arthur - for "how many were added" you can either add a counter in the loop, OR use `$UserList.Count`, OR compare the total before and the total after. i would not use the 3rd of those, tho. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks for your advice, I used '$UserList.Count' and it can work well. By the way, can you give me some advice about the code as below, i tired it but found some errors.

Comment: @Arthur - you are welcome! [*grin*] i presume you are talking about the Answer by `Vad`. i will comment there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant change content in your `$UserList` .More precisely, it is possible but affect the performance since You will need to read from the file and break it into segments. The best way is to download all users at once.You can do it like this:

```
$UserList=Get-ADGroupmember -identity adgroup | % { get-aduser $_.samaccountname | select userprincipalname } 
foreach ($UL_Item in $UserList)
    {
    $ARAGU_Params = @{
        TenantName = "contoso"
        HostPoolName = "contosoHostPool"
        AppGroupName = "Desktop Application Group"
        UserPrincipalName = $UL_Item.userprincipalname
        }
    Add-RdsAppGroupUser @ARAGU_Params
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your comment. I will have a test later and mark it. By the way, in the result of `Get-ADGroupmember`, there has on cell's content is **userprincipalname**, will it has some effect when I run the `Add-RdsAppGroupuser `?

Comment: yes it have effect. this parameter "The user principal name (UPN) of the user you would like to assign access to an app group."

Comment: I tried the comment and it finished with an error of **The specified UerPrincipalName does not exist in the Azure AD associated with the RD tenant**. > Is there a way can delete the title of **"userprinxipalname"**, just keep the UPN Like  > **One@contoso.com'
    'Two@contoso.com'** .  Now the 'UserList' have a title of userprincipalname, and I want to remove it just keep the content of the UPN like     'One@contoso.com'
    'Two@contoso.com'
    'Three@contoso.com'
    'Four@contoso.com'
    'Five@contoso.com'

Comment: @Vad - the `$UserList` collection looks like it will contain objects with one property - `userprincipalname`. however, when you use the objects you are refering to the whole object ... and  suspect the `UserPrincipalName = $UL_Item` should be `UserPrincipalName = $UL_Item.UserPrincipleName`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I changed it but there have an error. Should I change some other place like '$UL_Item in $UserList'?

Comment: @Vad I ran it but there have an error. Should I change some other place like **$UL_Item in $UserList**?

Comment: Run debug in powershell ISE and check what contain `$UL_Item.userprincipalname` on each step.

Comment: @Vad I didn't find something in '$UL_Item.userprincipalname'. That is why I ask if we should change the '$UL_item'? By the way, it there a way that I can delete the **''** mark in the $UserList = @(
    'One@contoso.com'
    'Two@contoso.com'
    'Three@contoso.com'
    'Four@contoso.com'
    'Five@contoso.com'
    )

Comment: just use my code, it write all userprincipalnames to variable and then run foreach for it. `$UserList = @(
    'One@contoso.com'
    'Two@contoso.com'
    'Three@contoso.com'
    'Four@contoso.com'
    'Five@contoso.com'
    )` must be deleted

Comment: @Vad Thanks, but the code finished with an error of **Cannot bind to parameter 'UserPrincipalName' because the argument is null.**

Comment: that mean you do something wrong, i check it and it work good

Comment: @Vad I only changed the adgroup, and the code upside can work well,  is there something wrong about the **$UL_Item.userprincipalname**, can you tell me the content of **$UL_Item.userprincipalname** when you run it?

Comment: @Arthur when i run it at first iteration it have value maxRight@work.com, at next iteration it LizaMeison@work.com ......

Comment: @Arthur - PLEASE, **_take the time to explore the items at each stage of your code_**. you cannot code things when you have no understanding of the _structure_ of the things you are working with. use `$Thing | Get-Member` & `$Thing | Select-Object -Property *` to get a solid understanding of the _structure_ of the objects. once you do that you will understand where your errors are coming from ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Vad Thanks so much for you comments, but when I run it there has no value, I will check again later.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks so very much, I will do that and try to find the errors.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I did it, thanks so much for your advice, hope you can teach me more.

Comment: @Vad Thanks so much for your code, it can work very well. I had mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Arthur - excellent! glad to know that you got it working ... [*grin*]